# If a continuous function on $[0,\pi]$ integrates to zero against cosines, it is identically constant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-series, approximation

> Let $f(x)$ is Continuous function on $[0,\pi]$,and for $n=1,2,.....,$ the function $f(x)$ has the following property:$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0.(n=1,2,......)$$
>   Proof: $f(x)\equiv C$(C is a constant) on $[0,\pi] .$

In my way of thinking ,applying  [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem), I could give the proof $f(x)\equiv C,$but I failed.
who can help me go futher about this ?Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can't prove $f\equiv 0$, since for example $f\equiv 1$ satisfies the conditions. Rather than the classical Weierstraß approximation theorem, use the Stone-Weierstraß approximation theorem for the system $\{1\} \cup \{\cos (nx) : n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\} \cup \{\sin (nx) : n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\}$, or Fejér's theorem. Or the $L^2$ theory of Fourier series.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer :I want to prove $f\equiv C$,not to prove $f\equiv 0！$.Friend, Maybe you misunderstand my question.

Comment: Well, you wrote "If $f(x)=a_{k}x^{k}+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\dotsc+a_{1}x+a_{0},$ for any infinite positive integer $n$ $(n=1,2,\dotsc)$ such that $\int_{0}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$.We can proof $f(x)\equiv 0,\forall x\in[0,\pi]$", and that's not true, I was referring to that in the first sentence. Anyway, it is easier to use trigonometric polynomials for that than ordinary polynomials. And be aware of a difference to the other question - which is quite unclear - _you_ demand that $\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, the other question only for some unspecified infinite subset

Comment: Perhaps the $0$ in that was just a typo. In that case, correct it, forget it and move on.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer:please give me some counterexample :"If $f(x)=a_{k}x^{k}+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+.......+a_{1}x+a_{0},$ for any infinite positive integer $n$ $(n=1,2,......)$ such that $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0$.We can proof $f(x)\equiv 0,\forall x\in[0,\pi]$ ."

Comment: Why do you write "any infinite positive integer $n$", by the way? Integers are all finite. But that aside, yes, if $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ and $\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, then $f$ is constant. I have indicated three (strongly related) methods of proving it in the first comment. Regarding the desired counterexample, I already gave one, $f(x) \equiv 1$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer:But "1" is a constant.I have already adjusted my question.

Comment: Hint: define $g\colon [-\pi,\pi] \to\mathbb{C}$ by $g(x) = f(\lvert x\rvert)$. Then $g$ is an even continuous function on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer：According to your hint,It is seemingly difficult for me to find the answer.but thanks for your help.

Comment: What are your problems? Take the Fourier series of $g$ and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to prove that a function $f$ is constant is to show that $$\int_0^\pi f(x)g(x)\,dx=0\tag{1}$$ for every function $g\in C[0,\pi]$  with zero mean (i.e., $\int_0^\pi g(x)\,dx=0$). Indeed, if $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$, then let $g$ be the function that is zero on most of the interval and has two triangular peaks at $x_1,x_2$: one  positive, one negative. This $g$ satisfies $\int_0^\pi g(x)\,dx=0$ but $(1)$ fails when the peaks are sufficiently narrow.

As Daniel Fischer noted, there are multiple ways to prove that the condition (1) is implied by 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx=0,\quad n=1,2,\dots \tag{2}$$
For example, one can use the fact that the cosine system is an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$, and thus excluding $1$ from it leaves us with the orthogonal complement of $1$.

Alternatively, use thw Stone-Weierstrass theorem to uniformly approximate $g$  by a linear combination of $\cos \pi n x$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$; observe that the coefficient of $\cos 0=1$ is small and therefore can be dropped while maintaining uniform approximation.